# Matching patterns in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I have an XML file which contains the following strings:

```
<field name="id">abcdef</field>
<field name="intro" > pqrst</field>
<field name="desc"> this is a test file. We will show 5>2 and 3<5 and try to remove non xml compatible characters.</field>
```

In the body of the XML, I have `>` and `<` characters, which are not compatible with the XML specification. I need to replace them such that when `>` and `<` are in:

```
 ' "> ' 
 ' " > ' and 
 ' </ '
```

respectively, they should **NOT** be replaced, all other occurrence of `>` and `<` should be replaced by strings "greater than" and "less than". So the result should be like:

```
 <field name="id">abcdef</field>
 <field name="intro" > pqrst</field>
 <field name="desc"> this is a test file. We will show 5 greater than 2 and 3 less than 5 and try to remove non xml compatible characters.</field>
```

How can I do that with Python?

Comment: Better to provide the result, rather then describe it.

Comment: You could try parsing the entire file using the python regexp module here http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Are all the improper uses of < and > in your file in the case of numerical expressions? If so this should be pretty easy, just replace "# > #", "#> #", and "# >#" with "# is greater than #" and "# < #", "#< #", and "# <#" with "# is less than #"

Comment: No, they are not all numerical. Basically the problem is I can not come up with a suitable regexp.

Comment: Your constraints would replace the '<'s at the beginning of each line as they don't fall into any of the 3 cases you provided where they should not be substituted. It might be easier to provide for the cases in which they are subsituted.

Comment: ok, so what you're saying is that these may not all be numerical comparisons, but they are all comparisons by value? I assume you wouldn't want to translate '>' and '<' to 'greater than' and 'less than' in cases of stream redirection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `lxml.etree.XMLParser` with `recover=True` option:

```
import sys
from lxml import etree

invalid_xml = """
<field name="id">abcdef</field>
<field name="intro" > pqrst</field>
<field name="desc"> this is a test file. We will show 5>2 and 3<5 and
try to remove non xml compatible characters.</field>
"""
root = etree.fromstring("<root>%s</root>" % invalid_xml,
                        parser=etree.XMLParser(recover=True))
root.getroottree().write(sys.stdout)
```

#### Output

```
<root>
<field name="id">abcdef</field>
<field name="intro"> pqrst</field>
<field name="desc"> this is a test file. We will show 5&gt;2 and 35 and
try to remove non xml compatible characters.</field>
</root>
```

Note: `>` is left in the document as `&gt;` and `<` is completely removed (as invalid character in xml text).

### Regex-based solution

For simple xml-like content you could use `re.split()` to separate tags from the text and make the substitutions in non-tag text regions:

```
import re
from itertools import izip_longest
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape  # '<' -> '&lt;'

# assumptions:
#   doc = *( start_tag / end_tag / text )
#   start_tag = '<' name *attr [ '/' ] '>'
#   end_tag = '<' '/' name '>'
ws = r'[ \t\r\n]*'  # allow ws between any token
name = '[a-zA-Z]+'  # note: expand if necessary but the stricter the better
attr = '{name} {ws} = {ws} "[^"]*"'  # note: fragile against missing '"'; no "'"
start_tag = '< {ws} {name} {ws} (?:{attr} {ws})* /? {ws} >'
end_tag = '{ws}'.join(['<', '/', '{name}', '>'])
tag = '{start_tag} | {end_tag}'

assert '{{' not in tag
while '{' in tag: # unwrap definitions
    tag = tag.format(**vars())

tag_regex = re.compile('(%s)' % tag, flags=re.VERBOSE)

# escape &, <, > in the text
iters = [iter(tag_regex.split(invalid_xml))] * 2
pairs = izip_longest(*iters, fillvalue='')  # iterate 2 items at a time
print(''.join(escape(text) + tag for text, tag in pairs))
```

To avoid false positives for tags you could remove some of `'{ws}'` above.

#### Output

```
<field name="id">abcdef</field>
<field name="intro" > pqrst</field>
<field name="desc"> this is a test file. We will show 5&gt;2 and 3&lt;5 and
try to remove non xml compatible characters.</field>
```

Note: both `<>` are escaped in the text.

You could call any function instead of `escape(text)` above e.g.,

```
def escape4human(text):
    return text.replace('<', 'less than').replace('>', 'greater than')
```

Comment: lxml-based solution: 3<5 becomes 35

Comment: @adray: yes. `<` is invalid in xml text so the xml parser can't parse it properly and `recover=True` option allows the parser to skip it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems I did it for `>`:

```
re.sub('(?<! " )(?<! ")(?! )>','greater than', xml_string)
```

`?<!` - negative lookbehind assertion,

`?!` - negative lookahead assertion,

`(...)(...)` is logical AND,

so whole expression means "substitute all occurences of '>' which (does not start with ' " ') and (does not start with ' "') and ( does not end with ' ')

case `<` is similar

Answer (score -3):

Use [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for XML parsing.

Comment: The ElementTree throws an exception because the XML has supposedly misplaced > and < characters.

Comment: @Mr_Spock: the point is that the XML is malformed, so ElementTree won't handle it. I just tried the `lxml.html` variant which can handle some malformed XML as well, but it too fails here.

Comment: I wonder why I received a downvote then.  The guy's question wasn't even clear then.  He didn't state what he was using until AFTER I brought up ElementTree.  Seems a little unfair.  I won't fret though.