# How to handle escaped string in lxml with Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I'm trying to use `lxml` to help me parse some XML files and output it. However,there are some special characters in the XML file. I don't want to replace it because it is too complicated to escape it and unescape it. Also I can't force the others to produce a well-formed XML.

Is there any way Python can let me handle the non-well-formed XML with lxml?

I can read it in properly:

```py
  parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
  root = etree.parse(sys.argv[1],parser=parser)
```

But when I want to print the element text, it can only print the content until the special character occurs.

```py
  for element in root.iter("content"):
    print("%s - %s  attr - %s" % (element.tag, element.text, element.get("name")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lxml does unescaping for you transparently. So you could try to fix invalid characters in the input first and then feed the result to lxml. For example, you could try a simple [regex-based solution to escape invalid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13322581/4279).

Answer (score 0):

A popular option to deal with less-than-perfect markup language files in Python is to use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  It can use many parsers, including lxml.

Can you post some of the XML that's giving you problems?