# Parsing special characters from xml in python

Tags: python

for values. Can anyone please tell me to parse value "<" using minidom.parse in python.

```
        <Value>"&lt;"</Value>

</Root>
```

Comment: May I know what output exactly you wants here ?

Comment: i send a request xml with "<" character for which i get response xml as above. Now i want to extract the "<" character for matching with those sent in request xml.

Comment: Not sure if it got lost in the edit or not, but `</ResourceRecordSets>` was also missing from the 2nd to last line of your XML. Again, ensure you're working with valid XML before trying to parse.

Comment: you could try [regex-based solution to convert your xml-like input into xml](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13322581/4279) to be parsed by minidom later.

Answer (score 2):

Thats not valid XML, `"` and `<` are a [special characters in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-predefined-ent) and can't be included in a document like that.

Fix your XML by escaping the `"` and `<` symbols and `minidom` will work as expected.

For example:

```
<Value>&quot;&lt;&quot;</Value>
```

or:

```
<Value><![CDATA["<"]]></Value>
```

Comment: For OP: There are several online xml validators/formatter available to you as well to check your source for errors. An example of one: http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html

Comment: The code is modified in such a way that it takes < inside quotes "" and updates to sqlserver as "<". Now when response is received the value("<") is present as such in response xml. So i need to parse whole value("<") for a further match.

Comment: @user3087993 You can't. That is not XML. If you have a `<` character in your text file thats not part of an element, by definition **it isn't XML* as it isn't conforming to the XML spec. Fix your XML. The problem isn't your code, its your XML. Can I make that clearer?